# Creating Directories and Sub directories and getting files inside sub directories

Tags: java, file

I am using this code to create directory and sub directories. I want my file Example.xml should come inside this subdirectory.
Instead of file I am getting folder of file name.

```
import java.io.File;

public class CreateDirectoryExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("C:\\Directory1");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (file.mkdir()) {
                System.out.println("Directory is created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
            }
        }

        File files = new File("C:\\Directory2\\Sub2\\Sub-Sub2\\example.xml");
        if (!files.exists()) {
            if (files.mkdirs()) {
                System.out.println("Multiple directories are created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create multiple directories!");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Please help